# Building a 3D crane

Tags: modeling, workflow

I want to build a crane like this:

http://www.3dcadbrowser.com/th/1/3/3597.jpg

But I have no clue on how to approach all those pipes without going crazy.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to build it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could model a single segment of the crane using only a few cylinders:

[image]

And add an [*Array Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array) as shown here:

[image]